# delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times JAVA

Tags: java

```
public class EnoughIsEnough {
    public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOccurrences){

        int n = 0;
        for(int b: elements){
            for(int i =0 , i< elements.length;i++) {
                if(elements[b] == elements[i]){ 
                    n++; 
                }
                if (n > maxOccurrences) {
                    for(int k = b; k < elements.length -1 ; k ++) {
                        elements[k] = elements [k + 1]; 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }    
        return null;

    }
}
```

Hey im a total programming newbie and only familiar with the very basics and I came a cross this problem: 
I have to delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times  but I don't know if im getting close or not, I struggle to remove the occurrences out of the array and im not even sure if the code I wrote so far is accutally detecting them.
I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.
Because of my low rank im not able to view solutions on code wars and googling this problem didn't bring me any closer because of to complex code I don't understand.

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EnoughIsEnough {
    public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOccurrences){

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> occurence = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i : elements) {
            if(occurence.containsKey(i)) {
                occurence.put(i, occurence.get(i) + 1);
            } else {
                occurence.put(i, 1);
            }
        }
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i : elements) {
            if(occurence.get(i) < maxOccurrences) {
                al.add(i);
            }

        }
        int[] output = new int[al.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<al.size(); i++) {
            output[i] = al.get(i);
        }
        return output;
    }


}
```

Comment: Care to explain how your answer works? Code dumps won't help OP learn from their mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember which elements exceed the count so you don't add them to the returned array.

The best way to do that is to keep a frequency count of the elements in a map for easy referral.

```
int[] v = deleteNth(new int[] { 20, 37, 20, 21 }, 1); // return [20,37,21]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
v = deleteNth(new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 3); // return [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
```

Prints

```
[20, 37, 21]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2]
```

Here is the method.  As numbers are added to the return list, the map records them by incrmementing a count associated with the number.  If the count exceeds the `maxOccurrences` allowed, it is not added to the list when encountered.

```
    public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements,
            int maxOccurrences) {
        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i : elements) {
            count.compute(i, (k,v)-> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
            if (count.get(i) <= maxOccurrences) {
                ret.add(i);
            }
        }
        // here you could return the list or convert to an array (as I did) and return
        // that.
        return ret.stream().mapToInt(a->a).toArray();
    }
```